# AMPScript - Only Show RSS Items from Last 14 Days

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, date

When I try to use the below code, I'm not able to see a preview email; it just says there's an error in the email.

```
%%[

Var @xml, @titles, @title, @links, @link, @descs, @desc, @dates, @date, @cnt 

Set @xml = ContentArea("3618") 

Set @titles =
BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,"//item/title",1) 
Set @links =
BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,"//item/link",1) 
Set @descs =
BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,"//item/description",1) 
Set @dates =
BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,"//item/pubDate",1)


SET @rows = RowCount(@titles)
Set @date = Field(Row(@dates,@cnt), "Value")

IF @rows >= 1 THEN

    for @cnt = 1 to @rows do

        IF DateDiff(NOW(),@date, "D") <= 14 THEN


    for @cnt = 1 to @rows do 
        Set @title = Field(Row(@titles,@cnt), "Value") 
        Set @link = Field(Row(@links,@cnt), "Value") 
Set @desc = Field(Row(@descs,@cnt), "Value") ]%%


<h1><a title="%%=v(@title)=%%" alias="%%=v(@title)=%%"
href="%%=v(@link)=%%">%%=v(@title)=%%</a></h1>
<p>%%=v(@desc)=%% <br />%%=v(@date)=%%</p> </div>


%%[ 
        ENDIF
    NEXT @cnt 
ENDIF
]%%
```

Content Area 3618 is where I'm pulling in my RSS:

```
%%httpget; 0 "RSS FEED I'm USING"%%
```

[RSS Structure Example](http://dhdev.info/rss/test.rss)

Comment: What happens when you paste the raw RSS XML (without the CR & LF) as a value for your `@xml` variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you've got an extra `FOR` loop.  Maybe something like this is what you intended:

```
%%[

Var @xml, @titles, @title, @links, @link, @descs, @desc, @dates, @date, @cnt 

Set @xml = ContentArea("3618") 

Set @titles = BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,"//item/title",1) 
Set @links = BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,"//item/link",1) 
Set @descs = BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,"//item/description",1) 
Set @dates = BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,"//item/pubDate",1)

SET @rows = RowCount(@titles)

IF @rows >= 1 THEN

    for @cnt = 1 to @rows do

        Set @date = Field(Row(@dates,@cnt), "Value")

        IF DateDiff(NOW(),@date, "D") <= 14 THEN

            Set @title = Field(Row(@titles,@cnt), "Value") 
            Set @link = Field(Row(@links,@cnt), "Value") 
            Set @desc = Field(Row(@descs,@cnt), "Value") 

            ]%%

            <h1><a title="%%=v(@title)=%%" alias="%%=v(@title)=%%" href="%%=v(@link)=%%">%%=v(@title)=%%</a></h1>
            <p>
                %%=v(@desc)=%% 
                <br />%%=v(@date)=%%
            </p>

            %%[ 
        ENDIF

    NEXT @cnt

ENDIF
]%%
```

Comment: Thanks Adam!  I updated the code to remove the extra "for" loop, but I'm still getting:

Invalid value specified for function parameter.
Function Name: Row
Parameter Name: Index
Parameter Ordinal: 2
Parameter Type: Numeric

Comment: Updated my example.  The setting of `@date` was in the wrong place.  Needed to be inside the loop, since it referenced `@cnt`.

Comment: Hmm...looks like all my RSS items are showing and not just the ones from the past 14 days; do I need to do anything to reformat my dates in the RSS feed?

Comment: I just swapped the DateDiff so @date was listed first; that did the trick.